# Why did The Dude go to the doctor?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-big-lebowski

In The Big Lebowski, Maude sends The Dude (or his Dudeness) to the doctor to check his jaw. The doctor asks him to take his pants off, and then he comes out of the exam with a grin on his face (although this could well be his general happiness).

We later learn that she's selected him to be the father of her child, but why did she send him to the doctor? It's implied it's related but if it was so he could be a donor why did she visit him in his apartment?

Comment: Can I just say I love that you add, "or his Dudeness," in parenthesis? :P

Comment: Are you asking why the Dude went to the doctor or why Maude sent the Dude to the doctor? If it's the latter, I think you should update the title.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**She wanted him to be examined to make sure he was fertile and healthy to be the father of the child she wanted.** It's possible that the exam could have included a virility exam, which would include a check for sperm count, which is usually done by examining a sperm sample. As such, The Dude may have masturbated during the exam to provide the sample, and his smile was from him feeling good or thinking, "Well, that was nifty, never had to do that in an exam before," as he left.

All of this is generally implied later after The Dude and Maude have sex and are talking in bed.

> The Dude: "Oh, so that doctor, um . . ."
>
> Maude: "Exactly."

I believe she visits him at his apartment to have sex because she's clearly shown to be a very sexual woman and wants to have her child as a product of sex, not artificial insemination or anything like that.

Comment: But if that's the case, wouldn't it be immediately obvious to the Dude what was going on? It only seems to occur to him later after he and Maude have had sex and they are talking about it.

Answer (score -2):

the doctor checked him for Sexually-transmitted diseases and general health; while a sperm count could conceivably be performed, there is little need and quite the unbelief factor that the dude would have accepted that as a normal exam.

Comment: Are you **sure**, or is this speculation?

Comment: When I saw the movie I assumed it was STDs.    I'd not considered sperm count.    I think it would be stupid for her to have him checked for virility and not STDs given her plan to have unprotected sex with him.

Answer (score -3):

Prostate exam.  The song was, after all, called "ooh, lookin' [out] my backdoor."

I know it's not as sexy as a sperm count, but it's plausible.